# How to emit specific messages after action is executed?

Tags: smart-contract

In solidity, we can emit many type messages when transaction finished, but in eos, I did't find it. I see the require_receipt api to notify the listeners the action but not the action result.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Contracts can emit inline actions. These may trigger other contracts, or they may do nothing. Full nodes may have plugins which listen for these inline actions to trigger off-chain behavior.

Comment: thanks, I see the history plugin, which can listen receiver:action:actor, can you explain there 3 words to me?

Comment: That sounds like a potential SE question

Answer (score 1):

EOS provides various get commands to access the results.

See the links below for the various get commands.
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#get